# rescale images in canvas after resetting it's ratio

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple canvas on my page that looks like this:

[image: Default canvas view]

The canvas is responsive so the size can increase and decrease depending on the screen you are looking at. What remains the same is the resolution of the result. This will always be scaled to a pre-set default of 1000x1000px.

This works with a scaling ratio.

Example: the canvas is 500x500 px on your screen, this means the scaling ratio is 0.5, if your screen is big enough to fit the 1000x1000 canvas on it. The ratio will be 1.0 and so on.

The canvas also has the option to add an image to it. Those images have to size accordingly to your screen size as well and just like the complete canvas, it will be resized to it's proper size before saving(1000x1000).

When you upload an image it is usually quite big on the canvas like so:

[image: Uploaded image to canvas]

Right now the size of the image is too big to completely show on the canvas and at this point it's individual scaling ratio is 1.0 while the scale ratio of the canvas remains at 0.5.

If i want to resize the image so it fits nicely within the canvas I get the following :

[image: The resized image]

To make sure the size of the image is not returned to it's default scale of 1.0 like when I uploaded it I added the following code :

```
canvas.on('object:modified', function (options) {

    options.target.set({
        width: options.target.getWidth(),
        height: options.target.getHeight(),
        scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1,
    });

});
```

This will set the X and Y scale to 1 after resizing/modifying. This way every time you change it's size, that point will be the new 1.0 scale.

To scale all my objects i wrote the following function :

```
function scaleObjects()
{
    // page has been resized therefore we recalculate the aspect ratio for the canvas.
    $windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $windowHeight = $(window).height();

    //currentCanvasWidth = $windowWidth;

    var PrevHeightRatio = canvas.getHeight() / canvasHeightDefault;
    var PrevWidthRatio = canvas.getWidth() / canvasWidthDefault;

    resizeCanvas();

    var HeightRatio = canvas.getHeight() / canvasHeightDefault;
    var WidthRatio = canvas.getWidth() / canvasWidthDefault;
    var objects = canvas.getObjects();


    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i].scaleX = WidthRatio;
        objects[i].scaleY = HeightRatio;

        var multiplierW = 1 / PrevWidthRatio;
        var multiplierH = 1 / PrevHeightRatio;

        var originalStartX = objects[i].left * multiplierW;
        var originalStartY = objects[i].top * multiplierH;

        objects[i].left = originalStartX * WidthRatio;
        objects[i].top = originalStartY * HeightRatio;
        objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

This will run every time a resize or a canvas save occurs.

The problem is that whenever I save or resize my canvas the current scale of the canvas gets applied to my images/objects. In this case my image is at a scale of 1.0 and my canvas at 0.5, saving or resizing will apply the 0.5 scale to the object and decrease its size. I would however like it to scale exactly like the rest of my canvas so nothing gets out of proportion.

How can i achieve this?

Here is an image of the canvas "After" resizing the page once :

[image: Canvas after resize]

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L6hob1e4/2/

Comment: On resize why don't you resize image also??? 
if possible create a snippet for this so it will be easy to solve. 
thanks

Comment: The images get resized at the same time the canvas is resized, therefore both are always scale at the same moments.

Comment: If possible create jsfaddle link for the same.

Comment: It is not possible for me to create a JSfiddle due to the size of this project and the dependancy's. I think all the information i just gave should be sufficient to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I did manage to create a JSfiddle after all. https://jsfiddle.net/L6hob1e4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and some testing i found the following solution.
I changed the for loop that scales the objects to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var previousH = (((objects[i].getHeight() / canvas.getHeight()) * canvasHeightDefault) * PrevHeightRatio);
        var previousW = (((objects[i].getWidth() / canvas.getWidth()) * canvasWidthDefault) * PrevWidthRatio);

        console.log(previousH + " - " + previousW);

        var multiplierSizeH = 1 / PrevHeightRatio;
        var multiplierSizeW = 1 / PrevWidthRatio;

        var onMaxH = objects[i].getHeight() * multiplierSizeH;
        var onMaxW = objects[i].getWidth() * multiplierSizeW;

        objects[i].height = onMaxH * HeightRatio;
        objects[i].width = onMaxW * WidthRatio;

        var multiplierW = 1 / PrevWidthRatio;
        var multiplierH = 1 / PrevHeightRatio;

        var originalStartX = objects[i].left * multiplierW;
        var originalStartY = objects[i].top * multiplierH;

        objects[i].left = originalStartX * WidthRatio;
        objects[i].top = originalStartY * HeightRatio;
        objects[i].setCoords();
    }
```

This will keep track of the size before and after the scaling which fixes the issue.